# get value from one function to another function using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

i want to get value from one function to the another function. and i want to pass the value to handler page. but in that i cant get the value to pass .. here i had given the code. please help me. for example assume that for radio=MR & fname=john.

```
function getdata()
{
   alert('hi');
   var radio = document.getElementsByName("radiobuttonlist1");
   for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++)
   {
    if (radio[i].checked)
    alert(radio[i].value);
   }

   var fname=document.getElementById("Firstnametxt").value;
   alert(fname);
}
```

here i want to get all those values to another function this is my another function.

```
function sendinfo()
{
getdata();

 $(document).ready(function(){     

   var url="Handler.ashx?radio="+radio+"&fname="+fname+""; "here i want the values from above function"

  alert(url);
    $.getJSON(url,function(json)
    {
        $.each(json,function(i,weed)
        {



        });

    });

});

}
```

thank you . help me

Comment: But you need to call the function first where the value will be assigned. Then use it for the second function. If you call the function before assigning , you'll not get your expected value

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this two ways.

### Option 1

You can define those variables outside of both functions like:

```
var radio;
var fname;
getdata() {
    radio = document.getElementsByName("radiobuttonlist1");
    fname=document.getElementById("Firstnametxt").value;
    // VALUE UPDATED HERE
}
sendinfo() {
    // VARIABLE ACCESSIBLE HERE
}
```

And then whenever the values of those variables is updated it will be updated at the scope those variables were initially defined (outside those functions).

The scope of a javascript variable is within the curly braces `{}` that variable is in and any curly braces within that set. Scope in javascript often refers to those curly braces `{}`. There are exceptions including the `if` statement in which you can define variables inside of and access outside (assuming the condition was true).

### Option 2

Or you can pass those variables as parameters to the second function like: `sendinfo(radio, fname);`

### Passing values by returning them

You can return the values as an object literal in your `getdata()` function like this:

```
getdata() {
    return {
        radio : document.getElementsByName("radiobuttonlist1"),
        fname : document.getElementById("Firstnametxt").value
    }
}
```

Then do this:

```
sendinfo() {
    var data = getdata();
}
```

And then access those variables like: `data.radio` and `data.fname`.

Comment: ok but i had done that what u said. its showing the alert as like thisHandler.ashx?radio=undefined&fname=undefined

Comment: Ah, thank you! Not a big user of JavaScript, but I was just looking to do this. Personally, I feel option 1 is just clearer for my little head... but I have to ask. Is this still considered a good practice in 2021? Cheers.

Comment: @deijmaster It depends on who you ask. Personally, I prefer the 2nd solution for most cases as the values can't be used out of order, and are garbage collected sooner.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare two variables globally,set them to the values you need in the first function and access them in the second function.

Answer (score 2):

```
var radio;
var fname;

function getdata()
{
   alert('hi');
   radio = document.getElementsByName("radiobuttonlist1");
   for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++)
   {
    if (radio[i].checked)
    alert(radio[i].value);
   }

   fname=document.getElementById("Firstnametxt").value;
   alert(fname);
}

function sendinfo()
{
    getdata();

     $(document).ready(function(){     

       var url="Handler.ashx?radio="+radio+"&fname="+fname+""; "here i want the values from above function"

      alert(url);
        $.getJSON(url,function(json)
        {
            $.each(json,function(i,weed)
            {



            });
        });
    });
}
```